# Deadlock when spawning goroutine in a for loop

Tags: go, goroutine

Consider the following [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PNSd2h0XPK)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    var chan_array [2]chan int

    chan1 := make(chan int)
    chan2 := make(chan int)

    chan_array[0] = chan1
    chan_array[1] = chan2


    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        go func() {

            select {
                case x := <- chan_array[i]:
                    if (x == 0) {
                        return
                    }       
                    fmt.Println(x)
            }
        }()
    }

    chan1<- 1
    chan2<- 2
    chan1<- 0
    chan2<- 0
}
```

The code above is trying to create 2 running goroutines with that listens to the channel to signal print or close.

But the above code run into dead lock.

I am not exactly sure why

Can someone point out my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Golang handle closures differently in goroutines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919213/why-does-golang-handle-closures-differently-in-goroutines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems:
**What is the value of `i` when `chan_array[i-1]` runs**:

```
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    go func() {
        select {
        case x := <- chan_array[i-1]:
            if x == 0 {
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(x)
        }
    }()
}
```

try this:

```
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    go func(i int) { 
        select {
        case x := <-chan_array[i]:
            if x == 0 {
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(x)
        }
    }(i)
}
```

Let's simplify your code (with some corrections):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    chan1 := make(chan int)
    chan2 := make(chan int)

    go routine(chan1)
    go routine(chan2)

    chan1 <- 1
    chan2 <- 2
    chan1 <- 0
    chan2 <- 0
}

func routine(ch chan int) {
    select {
    case x := <-ch:
        if x == 0 {
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}
```

With these:

```
chan1 <- 1
chan2 <- 2
```

fatal error:

```
all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

your goroutines finished and **no goroutines listening** to `chan1` and `chan1` here:

```
chan1 <- 0
chan2 <- 0
```

Your corrected working sample code is:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    chan1 := make(chan int)
    chan2 := make(chan int)

    go routine(chan1)
    go routine(chan2)

    chan1 <- 1
    chan2 <- 2
    chan1 <- 0
    chan2 <- 0
}

func routine(ch chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case x := <-ch:
            if x == 0 {
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(x)
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

By the time the goroutines are running the variable `i` has already incremented. Pass it as a function parameter instead.

In fact, never rely on variables from a function closure in goroutines. It's too unreliable.

Comment: I tried adding the parameter, but I am experiencing [dead lock](https://play.golang.org/p/SxcnORT6Ru).

Comment: @user3591466: Well, there's another problem. You send to the channels twice but your goroutines exit after receiving one value.