# Concurrent goroutines inside a for loop

Tags: go

I have written goroutine inside for loop as follow. What I want is to execute the goroutine for each item in the listofDevices list concurrently but this logic is running goroutine for only one item in the listofDevices list.

```
    for _, ip := range listOfDevices {
            inChan <- types.NewNotification(time.Now(), "/cloudtracer/status", nil,
                    &map[key.Key]interface{}{
                            key.New(ip): types.Pointer{Pointer: "/cloudtracer/status/" + ip},
                    })
            pingOneMachine := probe.NewPing(ip, 2*time.Second, inChan)
            // For now stopping the probe after few minutes. This will change later
            ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 2*time.Second)
            defer cancel()

            wg.Add(len(listOfDevices))
            go func() {
                    defer wg.Done()
                    pingOneMachine.Run(ctx)
            }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this out?
thanks in advance.

Comment: `wg.Add(len(listOfDevices))` in the loop seems wrong, move it before the loop. Or replace it with `wg.Add(1)`.

Comment: What is inchan defined as? Is it a buffered channel or a channel with a constant reader?

Comment: It looks like inchan has capacity of 1, play with bigger values.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the goroutine **closure**:

```
            go func(c context.Context) {
                    defer wg.Done()
                    pingOneMachine.Run(c)
            }(ctx) // pass in the lexically scoped variable here
```

That is, the `ctx` variable name is being overridden in the for loop before it is used in the goroutine (as the variables are lexically scoped), see this question for a nice explanation [Why does Golang handle closures differently in goroutines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919213/why-does-golang-handle-closures-differently-in-goroutines)

Basically variables are passed by reference:

> This means that any variables referenced within the closure from the "outer" scope are not a copy but are in fact a reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ;;{
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(ip string){
        defer wg.Done()
    }(ip)
}
wg.Wait()
```

It worked in creating parallel goroutines for all the ip addresses.

Answer (score -1):

do it like following

```
for ;;{
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(){
            defer wg.Done()
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
```